# ng-template issue in PrimeNG accordion

Tags: angular, accordion, primeng, ng-template

I wanted to create custom header and content in PrimeNG accordion component.
Unfortunately the result is this:

[image]

The main issue is that header is displayed only after clicking on accordion tab:

[image]

From this moment, header will be shown also when tab accordion is closed:

[image]

Any ideas about how troubleshooting this issue?
Please note that `Header` is just a placeholder, it will be replaced by custom content.

below is my code, no custom css has been applied to accordion and container tabs:

```
<p-tabView>
    <p-tabPanel header="Options" leftIcon='pi pi-cog'>
        <p-accordion multiple="false">
            <p-accordionTab [selected]="false">
                <ng-template pTemplate="header">Header</ng-template>
                <ng-template pTemplate="content">Content</ng-template>
            </p-accordionTab>
        </p-accordion>
    </p-tabPanel>
</p-tabView>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `selected` property from `p-accordionTab` should correct your problem.

Replace `<p-accordionTab [selected]="false">` with `<p-accordionTab>` (especially since default value of `selected` is false).

Comment: What about if I want to set one of the p-accordionTab to be selected, which is not the default behaviour?